# How to get graph with transaction support from remote gremlin server?

Tags: tinkerpop, gremlin-server, janusgraph

I have next configuration: remote Gremlin server (TinkerPop 3.2.6) with Janus GraphDB

I have gremlin-console (with janus plugin) + conf in remote.yaml:

`hosts: [10.1.3.2] # IP og gremlin-server host
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}`

So I want to make connection through gremlin-server (not to JanusGraph directly by `graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cassandra").set("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1").open();`) and get graph which supports transactions?

Is it possible? Because as I see all TinkerFactory graphs do not support transactions

Comment: Are you asking how to configure JanusGraph in Gremlin Server or how you would connect to and interact with a transactional graph over a remote connection to Gremlin Server?

Comment: @stephenmallette I would like to know how to do interact with JanusGraph over a remote connection to Gremlin server with transactional support. Is it possible? Is there an example somewhere (Java/Scala/Koltin examples)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understood to use the Janus graph through the gremlin server you should:

Define ip&port in the config file of the gremlin-console:

```
conf/remote.yaml
```

Connect by Gremlin-console to the gremlin server:

```
: remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==> Configured localhost/10.1.23.113: 8182
```

...and work in remote mode (using `:>` or `:remote console`), i.e. send ALL commands (or @script) to the gremlin-server.

```
:> graph.addVertex(...)
```

or

```
:remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [10.1.2.222/10.1.2.222:818]
graph.addVertex(...)
```

You don't need to define variables for the graph and the trawersal, but rather used

```
graph. - for the graph
g. - for the traversal
```

In this case, you can uses all graph features that are provided by the JanusGraphDB.

Answer (score 1):

Tinkerpop provides Cluster object to keep the config of connection. Using Cluster object graphTraversalSource object can be spawned.

```
this.cluster = Cluster.build()
                .addContactPoints("192.168.0.2","192.168.0.1")
                .port(8082)
                .credentials(username, password)
                .serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(GryoMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance())))
                .maxConnectionPoolSize(8)
                .maxContentLength(10000000)
                .create();
        this.gts = AnonymousTraversalSource
                .traversal()
                .withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

gts object is thread safe. With remote each query will be executed in separate transaction. Ideally gts should be a singleton object.

Make sure to call gts.close() and cluster.close() upon shutdown of application else it may lead to connection leak.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that connecting a java application to a running gremlin server using `withRemote()` will not support transactions. I have had trouble finding information on this as well but as far as I can tell, if you want to do anything but read the graph, you need to use "embedded janusgraph" and have your remotely hosted persistent data stored in a "storage backend" that you connect to from your application as you describe in the second half of your question. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/janusgraph-users/t7gNBeWC844
Some discussion I found around it here ^^ makes a mention of it auto-committing single transactions in remote mode, but it doesn't seem to do that when I try.

Comment: WithRemote supports transactions but for only 1 query. Each query is treated as a separate transaction. So what I do now is to club all writes, read into single query.  Tinkerpop provides many amazing steps to club every request into a single query.